# Fridge ice dispenser solenoid stuck?

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

My Bosch fridge developed a strange chemical smell around the ice dispenser, and the ice was collecting above the ice flap. After [disassembling the front panel](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1174901/Bosch-B26ft70sns.html?page=33), it seems like the smell is from the solenoid that opens the ice flap. The resistance across the terminals is infinite even at the highest rating on my multimeter, so I figure it's burnt out, thus leading to the smell and flap failure.

I can't seem to remove the solenoid though. I followed all of the steps, removed the screws, etc. but it's firmly stuck in there. I've given it a few good tugs, but it doesn't budge. It looks like the solenoid shaft should stay in place given the pictures, but given the way the plastic is warped around the shaft head it almost seems like the solenoid head punched through:

[image]

Am I just being too cautious, and I should tug this out hard, or is the solenoid perhaps jammed in some way and tugging harder will damage something?

Comment: I'd give it a *light* tap with a steel plier or something. A sharp hit might crack it loose if it is in fact the melted plastic that's holding it.

Comment: No dice. I think the shaft is actually anchored there and I'm supposed to pull out the solenoid casing, but it just wiggles and doesn't budge. It's like the shaft is fused to the casing or something. Thanks for the suggestion though, let me know if you think of anything else.

Comment: The photo appears to confirm the solenoid failure in a catastrophic manner. The lower right corner displays melted plastic!  Can you wedge a screwdriver or similar tool between the plastic cover over the coil and the metal bracket holding it in place?

Comment: Yup, that's why I included the obvious melted spot in the photo. From the manual's photos, the whole bracket is supposed to come out with the solenoid. I wedged a tool at the top of the solenoid bracket and applied considerable pressure, but it still didn't budge. I think I would crack the plastic at the top of the enclosure if I applied any more pressure. That's why I'm wondering if the solenoid shaft somehow got fused inside, or if I missed something. Thanks for all the suggestions!